# Closing a DB connection after API Request ends. Laravel RDS MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-rds

We are working on a application that is being used on large scale.
the app is hosted on the AWS architecture with (Ubuntu API Instances with RDS Database)

So when we do a load test on the API using jmeter we face issues on 10K  users as it shows Gateway time out issues on few request.
after debuging a requests and servers
we came to know that the Server capabilities are hitting 60% CPU only but the database connection limit's are reached

So we are now on increasing database connection capabilities but increasing db connection will have cause DB CPU reach 90% and it wil not work efficiently on all request coming

So we are thinking to disconnect the connection to databse after each api request being complete3d
for example

API : Get User

So once the api is being hit and result being returned it will disconnect the database connection of the request.

so in this case it will keep cloing connection for request once the  response is being served

So the closing connection is a good practice ?

Comment: You can think of adding a caching layer.

Comment: So you’re just guessing in the dark here? Brilliant idea … So what’s the point of closing those connections if you open them in the first place. If you close a 1000 connections you have opened a 1000 connections, closing solves nothing. You should profile the activity of a single user and map all database requests on idle. Figure out what can be cached and what can’t and work from there. Remember your plan was to reduce load, not to close connections ..